# 24hr time format string to sql time format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have a column that stores a value in 24 hr time format. It is a string/text that users enter on to the interface. I need to convert it into sql time format so that I can do time difference calculations. How can I convert the string to time? Example:

```
StringColumn   
1400
1600
```

needs to be

```
TimeColumn
1400
1600
```

so that I can calculate the time difference to get 2 hrs. Thanks.

Comment: Does the `StringColumn` store leading zeros? So `0900` not `900space` or `space900`?

Comment: They were instructed to enter 4 digits (24hr format) so the column is displaying 4 digits. Not sure if it is adding any space before or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string value are always 4 characters (meaning 01-09 and not 1-9 for early hours) then this works:

```
convert(time, stuff(StringColumn,3,0,':'))
```

Comment: Our staff enter the time as a string or text but in a 24hr format. So it will always be 4 digits. No space before or after. I need to covert it to time format now to get the time differces. Please leave me a solution and I will update you back tomorrow. Thank you all.

Comment: @sky_limit Then the code in my answer should work fine. It will return a value of time type that you can use with the datediff function to get difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conversion as in @jpw's answer, especially if you can use `DATEDIFF` on the results to get what you need.

Alternately you could perhaps do it as integer maths like:

```
SELECT (60*left('1900',2) + right('1900',2)) - (60*left('1400',2) + right('1400',2))
```

(I have used constants here, but you can replace `'1900'` and `'1400`' with column names).

Answer (score 1):

```
CAST(LEFT(Stringcolumn, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(Stringcolumn, 4), 2) AS TIME)
```